# D3 Multi-line Chart with categorical data on X-axis

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to draw a multiple line chart by using company branches data consisting of week days and values.

```
var data = [
    {
        "label": "branch-1",
        "values": [
            { "day": "Monday", "value": 20},
            { "day": "Tuesday", "value": 18},
            { "day": "Wednesday", "value": 29},
            { "day": "Thursday", "value": 31},
            { "day": "Friday", "value": 37},
            { "day": "Saturday", "value": 25},
            { "day": "Sunday", "value": 19}
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "branch-2",
        "values": [
            { "day": "Monday", "value": 32},
            { "day": "Tuesday", "value": 29},
            { "day": "Wednesday", "value": 37},
            { "day": "Thursday", "value": 41},
            { "day": "Friday", "value": 31},
            { "day": "Saturday", "value": 28},
            { "day": "Sunday", "value": 17}
        ]
    }
]
```

[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mQMH3/)

Firstly, I'm having problem with days on `x-axis`. Lines are not generated due to "d" attributes have Nan values instead of correct x-coordinates on svg paths. I know that I should not use minX, maxX for x.domain, but I can't find what to use instead.

Secondly, I use `d3.scale.category20()` function to generate colors. But I'd like to know if I can use more than 20 colors in case of having more than 20 branches. Is it possible by using `CSS`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinal scales need to have their domain set explicitly, that is, there's no notion of "min" or "max" for an ordinal domain. You have to do something like

```
x.domain(data[0].values.map(function (d) { return d.day; }));
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mQMH3/3/). As for the colours, you can set anything you want in CSS or in the D3 code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified my code accordingly and it works like a charm.